# node.js how to make one variable change apply to another one aswell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

Is there some kind of way of having some kind of "shared" variable? What I want to do is this:

```
var id = 5;
var player = new Player(id);

var array1[0] = player;
var array2[0] = player;

array1[0].id = 8

console.log(array1[0]); //8
console.log(array2[0]); //8
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm pretty sure this should work given that objects pass by reference.

Comment: Haven't tried that out as it doesn't even look logical to me

Comment: It's a good idea to try out an example before asking about it.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you do not store an object directly in a variable, but rather a reference to the object.

That means, you can have two variables that point to the same object - you simply copy the reference:

```
var a = {test: "test"};
var b = a;
console.log(a === b) // true
```

In this case, if you mutate the object via `a` and later read it via `b`, you will see the changes.

With the right implementation of `Player`, you can make that work for you:

```js
var Player = function(id) {
  this.id = id;
}
Player.prototype.setId = function(id) {
  this.id = id;
}
Player.prototype.getId = function() {
  return this.id;
}

var player = new Player(5);

console.log(player.getId()); // 5

var arrA = [];
var arrB = [];

arrA.push(player);
arrB.push(player);

console.log(arrA[0].getId()); // 5
console.log(arrB[0].getId()); // 5

arrA[0].setId(10);

console.log(arrA[0].getId()); // 10
console.log(arrB[0].getId()); // 10
```

[Check MDN for more info on working with objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)